# Product Details Page is blank Magento 2.3.2

Tags: frontend, magento2.3.2, frontend-error, product-detail-page

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getDefaultPlaceholderUrl() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml:29 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include() #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery\Interceptor), '/var/www/html/v...', Array) #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/v...') #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1094): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() #4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1098): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element{closure}() #5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(671): Magen in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml on line 29

Answer (score 0):

I have to fetch the same issue so Please, a ***check-In Database View*** is created or not If a **View** is not there so create view after run below command

```
rm -r generated/*
rm -rf var/*
cd pub/static
rm -r adminhtml
rm -r frontend

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:flush
```

may your issue resolve...

Answer (score 0):

Old question, however still relevant. Old template file catalog_product_view.xml is missing the helper that's present in gallery.phtml

Change

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="gallery_options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions</argument>
     </arguments>
</block>
```

to

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml">
         <arguments>
             <argument name="gallery_options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions</argument>
             <argument name="imageHelper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image</argument>
         </arguments>
</block>
```